# Passing data to Shiny modules from "global" data

Tags: r, shiny, module

I am trying to create a Shiny App but using modules stored in different scripts. I am having trouble calling the data to be used inside a module.

I have 2 App versions - the one where everything is stored inside a single Shiny R script and this works without issue. However, when I try to split it up into parts (a server and ui module) I get the error that the data can't be found.

Error:

[image]

App which works:

[image]

My question is, how can I pass the data to the server module so that I can perform the `mean` and `median` calculations?

App parts which do not work:

**My App:**

```
startDate <- as.Date("2023-01-01")
endDate <- as.Date("2023-06-01")
dates = seq.Date(from = startDate, to = endDate, by = "days")
dates <- rep(dates, each = 10)
propertyPrices <- round(rnorm(length(dates), mean = 100000, sd = 20000), 2)
purchases <- data.frame(collectionDate = dates, price = propertyPrices)
propertyRentals <- round(rnorm(length(dates), mean = 1000, sd = 200), 2)
rentals <- data.frame(collectionDate = dates, price = propertyRentals)

library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


ui_table_code <- modules::use("ui_code.R")
server_table_code <- modules::use("server_code.R")

ui <- fluidPage(

  ui_table_code$ui_controls("dygraph"),
  ui_table_code$ui_table("dygraph")

)


server <- function(input, output) {
  server_table_code$server_summary("dygraph")
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Server (server_code.R):**

```
modules::import("shiny", "moduleServer", "reactive", "renderTable")
modules::import("dygraphs", "renderDygraph", "dyOptions", "dySeries", "dyAxis", "dygraph")
modules::import("magrittr", "%>%")
modules::import("tibble", "column_to_rownames", "add_column")
modules::import("dplyr", "select", "filter", "bind_rows", "mutate", "ungroup", "summarise", "group_by", "n", "full_join", "case_when", "distinct", "bind_rows", "arrange")
modules::import("zoo", "rollapply")
modules::import("stats", "median")

server_summary <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    comprar_stats = reactive({
      purchases %>%
        filter(collectionDate > as.Date("2022-09-27")) %>%
        filter(price < 1000000) %>%
        filter(price > 100000) %>%
        group_by(collectionDate) %>%
        summarise(
          mean_price = mean(price),
          mean_price = round(mean_price, 0),
          propertiesListed = n(),
          median_price = median(price),
          median_price = round(median_price, 0)
        ) %>%
        ungroup()
    })
    mean_median_choice <- reactive({tolower(input$metric2)})
    output$myTable = renderTable({
      comprar_stats() %>%
        select(c("collectionDate", "propertiesListed", contains(mean_median_choice())))
    })
  }
  )
}
```

**UI (ui_code.R)**

```
modules::import("shiny", "NS", "selectInput", "tableOutput")
modules::import("purrr", "map_chr", "pluck")
modules::import("htmltools", "tagList", "tags")
modules::import("dygraphs", "dygraphOutput")

ui_controls <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  selectInput(
    ns("metric2"), "Select Mean or Median",
    choices = c("Mean", "Median"),
    width = NULL,
    selectize = TRUE,
    selected = "Mean"
  )
}


ui_table <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tags$div(
    class = "mytable",
    tableOutput(ns("myTable"))
  )
}
```

**App which works:**

```
    startDate <- as.Date("2023-01-01")
endDate <- as.Date("2023-06-01")
dates = seq.Date(from = startDate, to = endDate, by = "days")
dates <- rep(dates, each = 10)
propertyPrices <- round(rnorm(length(dates), mean = 100000, sd = 20000), 2)
purchases <- data.frame(collectionDate = dates, price = propertyPrices)
propertyRentals <- round(rnorm(length(dates), mean = 1000, sd = 200), 2)
rentals <- data.frame(collectionDate = dates, price = propertyRentals)

library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


ui_controls <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  selectInput(
    ns("metric2"), "Select Mean or Median",
    choices = c("Mean", "Median"),
    width = NULL,
    selectize = TRUE,
    selected = "Mean"
  )
}


ui_table <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tags$div(
    class = "mytable",
    tableOutput(ns("myTable"))
  )
}

server_summary <- function(id){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    comprar_stats = reactive({
      purchases %>%
        filter(collectionDate > as.Date("2022-09-27")) %>%
        filter(price < 1000000) %>%
        filter(price > 100000) %>%
        group_by(collectionDate) %>%
        summarise(
          mean_price = mean(price),
          mean_price = round(mean_price, 0),
          propertiesListed = n(),
          median_price = median(price),
          median_price = round(median_price, 0)
        ) %>%
        ungroup()
    })
    mean_median_choice <- reactive({tolower(input$metric2)})
    output$myTable = renderTable({
      comprar_stats() %>%
        select(c("collectionDate", "propertiesListed", contains(mean_median_choice())))
    })
  }
  )
}



ui <- fluidPage(

  ui_controls("dygraph"),
  ui_table("dygraph")


)


server <- function(input, output) {
  server_summary("dygraph")
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time I use the `modules` package. One option would be to pass your dataset from the global environment as an argument.

To this end add `purchases` as an argument ot the server function in `server_code.R`:

```
server_summary <- function(id, purchases){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    comprar_stats = reactive({
      purchases %>%
        filter(collectionDate > as.Date("2022-09-27")) %>%
        filter(price < 1000000) %>%
        filter(price > 100000) %>%
        group_by(collectionDate) %>%
        summarise(
          mean_price = mean(price),
          mean_price = round(mean_price, 0),
          propertiesListed = n(),
          median_price = median(price),
          median_price = round(median_price, 0)
        ) %>%
        ungroup()
    })
    mean_median_choice <- reactive({tolower(input$metric2)})
    output$myTable = renderTable({
      comprar_stats() %>%
        select(c("collectionDate", "propertiesListed", contains(mean_median_choice())))
    })
  }
  )
}
```

And in your main app code pass `purchases` to `server_summary`:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  server_table_code$server_summary("dygraph", purchases)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! thats exactly what I was looking for. I had the first part correct, I was just failing to pass it through to `server_table_code$server_summary("dygraph", purchases)`. Thanks again!